# Etymology of latin suffix -idus

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, latin

What is the (probably Indo-European) origin of the latin suffix -idus, as in "acidus"? Are there any known cognates?

Comment: Wiktinary gives reference to “-idus” on page 821 of the Oxford Latin Dictionary (1st ed., 1968–82) (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-idus#Latin)

Comment: Depends on whether you believe in laryngeal metathesis in Italic. I don’t think there’s any real, across-the-board consensus; personally I favour the explanation that it’s from _*tó_-participles to laryngeal-final stems (predominantly statives, hence its affinity with the second conjugation), with laryngeal metathesis.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So the idea is Ht > tH > tʰ > d? Are there other examples of laryngeal aspiration in Latin? And why doesn't it happen in e.g. *nōtus, nātus*?

Comment: @TKR Those are both syllabic laryngeals, so you wouldn’t expect it in those cases. The parade example is of course _*stéh2-tlo-m_ > _stabulum_, where the metathesis is seen both in the quality of the consonant (_b_ < _θ_) and the length of the vowel; the same is true if it’s _*-eh1-tó-_ > _-*e-tʰo-_ > PIt. _*-eθo-_ > Lat. _*-idus_ (with regular raising of both _*e_ and _*o_). It’s not quite so straightforward across the board, and there are counterexamples, but to me it solves a lot more problems than it creates.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet For non-syllabic Ht without metathesis cf. *vātis, Brūtus, tūtus* (if from tuh₂- as per de Vaan), and the suffix *-tāt-*. *Stabulum* is I believe usually derived from *sth₂-dʰlo-m, which seems more straightforward.

Comment: @TKR That in turn depends on how you view the _*-Tlo-_ suffix(es). If, as is held where I come from, they are allophones of the same suffix, roots in final _*h1_ or _*h2_ is exactly where we find _*-dʰlo-_ (~ _*-tʰlo-_); these allophones are then the result of laryngeal metathesis. Many seeming counterexamples are taken to be analogical (e.g., the regular part. in _-ētus_ in 2c.) – basically any form created after the disappearance of the laryngeals – but yes, also some genuinely problematic forms, though I can’t recall offhand which category your examples here fit into.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But that allomorphy is a PIE pattern. So *-idus*, if related, would represent an Italic survival of a PIE rule that has elsewhere largely been obscured by analogy -- is that the idea? (Tangentially, deriving *stabulum* from an e-grade seems problematic in any case, since metathesis would give stéth₂lom with no vowel coloring, unless one says the coloring preceded the metathesis; you'd think there should be other examples of this with laryngeal-final roots in that case. And cf. Skt. *sthātrám* with long ā from e-grade.)

Comment: @TKR Yes, that’s the idea. It was a PIE allomorphy, and there are scattered vestiges of it here and there, but it’s left no real regular traces because the vast majority of the contexts where it operated would be at the intersection of roots and productive suffixes where analogy is so easy to turn to. I do think this is said to be a _late_ PIE allomorphy, so productive after colouring, but I’d have to read up on the details.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The problem I see with relating *-Tlo-* to *-idus* is that in the former case, full-grade *-eH-tl- / -eH-dʰl-* gives a long vowel, even accepting the metathesis/allomorphy account (cf. many of the examples in Olsen 1988 which I think originated this idea). So sa far as I can see you'd expect *-eh₁t- > -ēd-*.

Answer (score 1):

Latin opposes participles with -nt- (active) to -d- (passive-stative).
If you believe in Kortlandt's effect, that is to say the alternation between *H1 and *d in a number of words and roots, then -d- in timi-d-us and -eH1- in tim-e-o are basically the same morpheme *-d- with and without Kortlandt's effect.